# How to find duplicates from a full data frame using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame with 3 columns of classes and 5 rows of students in each class. Some of these students are duplicates. I want to list the most common student names from all the classes and list them in descending order, the number of times they exist, and which the classes they exist in.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'biology': ['ryan', 'sarah', 'tom', 'ed', 'jackson'],
    'statistics': ['sarah', 'ed', 'jacob', 'ryan', 'de'],
    'ecology': ['austin', 'ryan', 'tom', 'sam', 'sarah']
})

   biology statistics ecology
0     ryan      sarah  austin
1    sarah         ed    ryan
2      tom      jacob     tom
3       ed       ryan     sam
4  jackson         de   sarah
```

I want the output look something like this:

```
ryan, 3 classes, (biology, statistics, ecology)
sarah, 3 classes, (biology, statistics, ecology)
tom, 2 classes, (biology, ecology)
ed, 2 classes, (biology, statistics)
jackson, 1 class, (biology)
jacob, 1 class, (statistics)
de, 1 class, (statistics)
austin, 1 class, (ecology)
```

...and so on

Any help would be appreciated, I'm a beginner so I have been at this for a several hours. Brain is getting killed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) the DataFrame to get to long form, then [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with Named Aggregation to get both the number of classes, and the names of the classes, lastly we can [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to get the highest frequency students first:

```
output_df = (
    df.melt(var_name='class name', value_name='student name')
        .groupby('student name', as_index=False)
        .agg(class_count=('class name', 'count'),
             classes=('class name', tuple))
        .sort_values('class_count', ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
)
```

`output_df`:

```
  student name  class_count                         classes
0         ryan            3  (biology, statistics, ecology)
1        sarah            3  (biology, statistics, ecology)
2           ed            2           (biology, statistics)
3          tom            2              (biology, ecology)
4       austin            1                      (ecology,)
5           de            1                   (statistics,)
6      jackson            1                      (biology,)
7        jacob            1                   (statistics,)
8          sam            1                      (ecology,)
```

---

We can further conditionally add classes/class to `class_count` and write [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
# Conditionally Add Classes/Class
output_df['class_count'] = output_df['class_count'].astype(str) + np.where(
    output_df['class_count'].eq(1),
    ' class',
    ' classes'
)
# Write to CSV
output_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

`output.csv`:

```
ryan,3 classes,"('biology', 'statistics', 'ecology')"
sarah,3 classes,"('biology', 'statistics', 'ecology')"
ed,2 classes,"('biology', 'statistics')"
tom,2 classes,"('biology', 'ecology')"
austin,1 class,"('ecology',)"
de,1 class,"('statistics',)"
jackson,1 class,"('biology',)"
jacob,1 class,"('statistics',)"
sam,1 class,"('ecology',)"
```

---

Setup and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'biology': ['ryan', 'sarah', 'tom', 'ed', 'jackson'],
    'statistics': ['sarah', 'ed', 'jacob', 'ryan', 'de'],
    'ecology': ['austin', 'ryan', 'tom', 'sam', 'sarah']
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'biology': ['ryan', 'sarah', 'tom', 'ed', 'jackson'],
    'statistics': ['sarah', 'ed', 'jacob', 'ryan', 'de'],
    'ecology': ['austin', 'ryan', 'tom', 'sam', 'sarah']
})

results = {}
for h in df:
    for k,v in df[h].value_counts().items():
        print(k,v)
        if k in results:
            results[k]['value'] += v
            results[k]['class'].append(h)
        else:
            results[k] = {'value':v,'class':[h]}
results = {h:results[h] for h in sorted(results, key=lambda x:results[x]['value'],reverse=True)}
```

Comment: There does not appear to be a `student name` column in the shown dataframe.

Comment: You can replace student_name with what ever the column is that has the names of the students.

Comment: It appears that there are many columns each containing students, and the goal is to obtain (A) the number of columns a particular student is in, and (B) the list of columns under which the student appears. This does not appear to address either of those goals.

Comment: Sorry I just saw the updated post that displays the dataframe a little better, I'll try and update my answer for you.